How to display the identifier after the execution of a DDL statement?
Postgresql (the command line tool psql) reports this after each DDL statement:
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TRIGGER
INSERT 0 2
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE FUNCTION
INSERT 0 4
CREATE TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
INSERT 0 7
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TYPE

Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL to report also the identifier instead of just the type?

Are you talking about the server or about psql, the client? I don't think you can change psql like that.
